# Server error in Kohana

Tags: kohana

Quick question.

Why do I get the following error and how can I solve it?

```
require_once() [function.require-once]: open_basedir restriction in effect.
File(/lib/swift_required.php) is not within the allowed path(s):
(/home/thnk/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. The issue was happening because I was using a wrong path for the library.

I was trying to call the library from:

```
/lib/swift_required.php
```

And it should be located somewhere like here:

```
$basePath = '/home/mydomain/domains/mydomain.org/public_html/myapp/';
require_once($basePath . 'system/vendor/swift/Swift/lib/swift_required.php');
```